# One to many select statement

Tags: mysql

I have `quizzes` table with columns `id, quiz_name, owner_user_id` and second table called `user_answer` with columns `id, quiz_id, user_id, answer_id`

I want to select quiz name, quiz id, and all users who played particular quiz with the given id. Can I do this with one SQL statement?

Later I need to pass this result in JSON

Comment: Yes of course you can. This is what a database is all about. It contains relational data and you write a query to select the data. What makes you think you can't? You may want to start with drawing a table (columns and rows) of the desired result for a quiz ID. The result columns show you what to put into your query's select clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to join tables on quiz_id and select everything you want.
This is the code if you want quiz name, quiz id and user ids.

```
SELECT q.quiz_name, q.id, u.user_id 
from quizzes q join user_answer u on (q.id = u.quiz_id) 
where q.id = {yourID}
```